# Check date if valid date

Tags: excel, vba

Excel experts,

I have a problem in validating the date in excel.

Is there any method that I can use if the user enter a invalid date?

> For eg. If user entered `11/31/2020`.

We all know November only has 30 days. I've already searched but always result only is formatting the date.

[image: Actual Result]

Comment: How does the user enter this? Input box? Or straight into the cell, in that case you are dealing with string data.

Comment: Straight into cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### To verify

The formula below returns FALSE if a date is not recognized in Excel, e.g. 11/31/2020 is recognized as text.

```
=ISNONTEXT(A1)
```

### A better solution

What i would suggest however is to select the range of cells where dates are inputted, click Data -> Data Validation -> Select Allow: Date -> Data: Greater than: 1 (same as 01-01-1900), now the user will be prompted with an error message whenever an invalid date is entered.

Comment: Kudos for your second solution!

Comment: The second solutions is working

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(DAY(A1)),"Date","Invalid Date")`

Comment: Very useful.  Tried it out with a valid date and also `35/02/2024`, `21/13/2024` and `21/02/xxx`.  Flagged each of the invalid dates as invalid, even though it was only checking `DAY()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help even though it's been a long time since you asked this, but it might help someone else.
This work exactly as you need it to as I have used it myself.

1. Select the cell or range you wish to apply the validation to.
2. Then click: Data -> Data validation -> Add rule -> Criteria -> Is valid date.
3. Click on "Advanced options" and tick "Reject the input".

Now if someone enters an invalid date like 11/31/2020 it will not allow it and an error box will pop; when you click "ok" on the error pop up, the box will close but the date will automatically change to the exact date of that day.

One thing to keep in mind is your date format (US: mm/dd/yyyy, UK and rest of the world: dd/mm/yyyy), although I don't think it matters much, the system should recognise either format but note that just in case.

Make sure that in the 'Apply to range section' you have selected or included the cells you need.